# How to create non time based HeatMap in grafana?

Tags: grafana

I have coordinates x and y, how much time ( in milliseconds) the user spent in each dot/coordinate and the time he visited that dot. 
Can I create a HeatMap in Grafana where the axes are x and y and the color is based on time spent on that dot?

Comment: There is no support of non-time XY axis in Grafana's Heatmap panel currently.

You can partially simulate heatmap with (non-graphical) `Table` panel with durations as cell values and cell value mapped to cell color. `x` can go to first column cells and `y` values used as column titles.
Whether you can query data in proper format or not depends on datasource capabilities though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a good way to do this in any of Grafana's standard templates. You might be able to find a way with one of their plugins (maybe the Bubble Chart?), but none of them look like they do exactly what you're looking for. 
https://grafana.com/plugins?type=panel